# Why did Loyalists go to Canada during the American Revolution

Tags: british-empire, american-revolution, canada

I am currently learning about the American Revolution and I have some questions about the loyalists.

I know that they were supportive of the British Empire, but why did they leave the U.S. and, when they got to Canada, what were they promised for their loyalty? All I know is that they were promised land because of their loyalty to go to Canada. And one reason why they went to Canada was to settle there. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the Wikipedia article on Loyalists (American Revolution)? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loyalist_(American_Revolution) What is you want to know that is not already there?

Comment: @LarsBosteen Sorry my english not very good, I don't really understand the article.

Comment: Have you tried translating (Google translate)? Or you may be able to right click on the article and translate into your own language.

Comment: There's also a [Simple English version of that article](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loyalist_\(American_Revolution\)), which might help. There are Simple English versions of many articles and it can be useful if English is not your native language. Look at the sidebar for the list of languages on an article or change `en.wikipedia.org` to `simple.wikipedia.org` in the address bar.

Comment: There's a French version of the article at https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loyalistes_(r%C3%A9volution_am%C3%A9ricaine) (assumption based on "come to Canada"in the question title, but English not being your first language, also your profile's refernce to poutine.  Apologies if it's wrong)

Answer (score 31):

[Loyalists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loyalist_(American_Revolution)) who lived in the 13 colonies fled to Canada because Canada was part of the British Empire.  In Canada they could still be British.  If they stayed in the colonies they would be traitors to the King.

> When their cause was defeated, about 15% of the Loyalists (65,000–70,000 people) fled to other parts of the British Empire, to Britain itself, or to British North America (now Canada). [*Wikipedia*](http://When%20their%20cause%20was%20defeated,%20about%2015%25%20of%20the%20Loyalists%20(65,000%E2%80%9370,000%20people)%20fled%20to%20other%20parts%20of%20the%20British%20Empire,%20to%20Britain%20itself,%20or%20to%20British%20North%20America%20(now%20Canada).)

There was much more land available in Canada than in Britain.  As @reirab points out,

> The entirety of Great Britain fits inside the province of British Columbia alone... 4 and a half times! Granted, most of the land in Canada is also much colder than Britain for a large portion of the year.

Land was very important; land was wealth.  Land was more important than income.  Land was vital for economic and political rights - the true importance of owning land is difficult to explain without a long article on the theory of British rights & politics.

*Simplified since OP said that the Wikipedia article presented linguistic challenges*

Comment: They used to lived in the 13 colonies correct?

Comment: Yes. I have edited my answer.

Comment: "There was much more land available in Canada than in Britain." This is a significant understatement. :) The entirety of Great Britain fits inside the province of British Columbia alone... 4 and a half times! Granted, most of the land in Canada is also _much colder_ than Britain for a large portion of the year.

Comment: @reirab: Nothing west of Sault Ste. Marie was part of *Canada* in the 1780's; everything further west (and north) was *Rupert's Land*, later the North-West Territory, and run as a fur-trapping preserve by the Hudson's Bay Company until circa 1870. However, substantial land grants were granted in what is now Southern Ontario, where the former inhabitants,  Huron/Algonquian peoples, had been largely destroyed by disease and warfare with the Iroquois. Southern Ontario is substantially **hotter** than everywhere in Britain for the summer months, June to September.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Yes, I'm aware. That's why I said "for a large portion of the year," not "all year." Eastern (and Central) North America does not enjoy the moderating effect of the Atlantic Ocean being upwind that exists in Great Britain.

Comment: @reirab: Southern Ontario is also much further south than Great Britain. the land grants near modern Brantford and London, Ontario, are at roughly the latitude of Bilbao Spain: ~ 43 degrees, 20' north.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I'm aware. Yet, Windsor is much, much colder than London in the winter. In the coldest part of the year in London, about 10% of days have lows below freezing. In the coldest part of the year in Windsor, about 10% of the days have lows _above_ freezing. Heck, I live in Tennessee at about the same latitude as Gibraltar (36.2 degrees N) and, even here, the winters are significantly colder than London (though, of course, summer is much hotter.)

Answer (score 6):

The [Loyalists](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-ushistory/chapter/patriots-and-loyalists/) supported the losing side during the American Revolution. That's because they represented only about 15% of the American population, versus 45% for the Revolutionaries. After the Declaration of Independence, most pro-British officials were chased out of the colonies, and most Loyalists hid their views, at least until the British army came to their communities.

During and immediately after the war, Loyalists were mistreated and shunned by the winning and later victorious Patriots. Some attempts were made to conciliate them after the war, but many felt that it would be better to start fresh under British rule elsewhere, with some financial assistance from Britain for their loyalty.

Comment: See "United Empire Loyalist" for a Canadian perspective...

Comment: Who made up the last 40% of the American population?

Comment: @Nosrac what I've always read was that there was a 33/33/33 split between Revolutionaries, Loyalists and "Indifferents".  I'm skeptical, though, since that many Loyalists could have easily helped to defeat the Revolutionaries.

Comment: @RonJohn that many *sufficiently motivated* Loyalists. It's one thing to say you like the king, it's another to die for him.

Comment: @Nosrec: The last 40% were "fencesitters" or "Undecided."

Comment: @RonJohn: The history books "finessed" it by saying "one third, one third, one third," but as a practical matter, the Revolutionary "third" was larger (but not a majority), the fence sitter "third" was in the middle. and the pro-Crown "third" was the smallest. That would be true even if you contested the percentages I cited from the source I linked.